# Titleps: even/odd custom headers with subsection information

Tags: formatting, titleps

I am using the Titleps package to format my custom headers (document class is scrartcl). I want section and subsection information in my header with specific formatting. The relevant code is:

```
%pagestyle
\settitlemarks{section,subsection,subsubsection}
\newpagestyle{mypage}{%
  \headrule
  \sethead[\MakeUppercase{\fontsize{9}{12} \selectfont\thesection\quad \sectiontitle}]%
        []%
        [\fontsize{9}{12} \selectfont\thesubsection\quad \subsectiontitle]%
        {\fontsize{9}{12} \selectfont\thesubsection\quad \subsectiontitle}%
        {}%
        {\MakeUppercase{\fontsize{9}{12} \selectfont\thesection\quad \sectiontitle}}%
  \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}%
}
```

The problem is with the subsection information on the odd pages ({} section): it seems not to be there. The code in general seems correct as any text I put into the odd section will be displayed as intended. The even pages are fine. Any ideas how to fix this?

Cheers,
anne

PS:
Here are my package includes:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{udsblau}{rgb}{0.062745, 0.25882, 0.47843}
\usepackage[bookmarks = true, hidelinks = true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage[numbers, round]{natbib}
\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\headheight}{1.5cm}
\usepackage[top=2.3cm, bottom=2cm, inner=2.5cm, outer=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} %bold captions
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{titleps}
```

The header on the even pages is correct. It should be mirrored on the odd pages:
[image]

Comment: Why don't you use KOMA's footer/header stuff, which is designed to cooperate fully with this class, rather than `titleps`? I assume the use of `geometry` is to meet some arbitrary institutional requirement, so that you probably can't help. `subfigure` is obsolete. `times` is obsolete. You are loading `hyperref` much, much too early. Please provide a complete minimal example we can compile.

Comment: Please read the `titleps` documentation careful. With your code `\subsectiontitle` is reset in `\section`. Depending on which mark is used on even/odd pages `\subsectiontitle` can be empty. With your twosided document you can try option `outermarks`. But maybe then the subsection entry will be missed on other pages. Note, that replacing `titleps` by `scrlayer-scrpage` will not solve this issue.  I would suggest to use only the section information in article classes like `scrartcl`.